# is ``: m_var(var)`` faster than ``m_var = var``

Tags: c++, class

There are two ways of quickly setting up a class that I know of

**A:**

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(File& file) :
    m_file(file)
{}
```

**B:**

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(File& file) :
{
    m_file = file;
}
```

is there a *performace* related reason to use one over the other or is it just coding standards.

Comment: What's the type of `m_file`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat its just a general question, Though in my project ``File`` is just a struct that stores filepath and some other useful stuff that the app could ask for

Comment: So it's not a reference? Then having a non-const ref as a parameter is probably wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it was just a general question about the performance difference between the two contractor's and initialization lists. My apologies still.

Comment: There is no general answer, since it depends both on what `File` is, and what type `m_file` is.  The first initialises `m_file` directly from `file`, and the second default initialises `m_file` and then assigns it.  Depending on what the types are, one or both approaches may be infeasible.  For example, it is not possible to default-initialise an instance of a class with no constructor that accepts no arguments.  If both approaches *are* feasible, their relative performance is described as "it depends".  Practically, however, the preferred default choice is the first.

Comment: correctness is much more important than performance. The two aren't doing the same thing, hence performance is secondary. Worries about performance is for when you have working code and want to compare different versions that are equivalent in what they do

Answer (score 1):

**It depends**.

In the first case, `m_file` is constructed directly from `file`.

In the second case, `m_file` is default-constructed first, then updated from `file`, undoing whatever the constructor had initialized.

So, depending on what type `m_file` is declared as, and what its default constructor does or does not do, there *may* be performance differences.